# How can I pass an array parameter using Neo4j.Driver?

Tags: .net, neo4j

Let's say I have the following query to be executed on Neo4j 3.0:

```
let cmd =   """
                match 
                  (u:User {userId: {userId} })
                , (p:Permission {permissionId: {permissionId} })
                merge 
                (u)-[r:can{
                            dateCreated: {dateCreated},
                            dateChanged: {dateModified},
                            allowed: [{allowed}],
                            denied: [{denied}],
                            createdby: {createdBy},
                            changedby: {modifiedBy}
                }]->(p)
                return r
            """
```

The relationship `Can` have an array property called `allowed`.

With the code above I tried to pass `"item1,item2"` but the it created only a single item in the array. How can I pass the items correctly so I can have multiple items inside the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allowed` and `denied` values should be arrays, and the Cypher code should be changed to use those values as-is (instead of inside brackets):

```
    ...
    allowed: {allowed},
    denied: {denied},
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly :)